# Render taking extremely long for only 250 frames

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Hi I'm new to blender and have been making car animations. My first render which was only 2 seconds took over 2 hours to render. I thought that might be normal but today my render of only 250 frames has taken over 10 hours and is still not done. I have an i5 processor and a gtx 2060 gpu. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Which render engine are you using?

Comment: May there is no space in the RAM to render it. Render tooks a lot of RAM space.

Comment: I am using Eevee

Comment: Could be anything, look up scene optimization for rendering. Maybe you have too much geometry, or you didn't bake your physics, or it could be a volume which is set to low voxel-wise, or several other things.

Comment: How long is a single frame been rendered? In animation rendering, you should minimize the time to 1~10 minute if you are using EEVEE. If the single frame render over 10 min, you should probably check is there any undesired complicated thing blocking your rendering time.